# Creating a sublist for elements within a list of lists after creation of list object

Tags: r, list, recursion

Sample list:

```
sublist <- list(foo = "foo", bar = "bar", baz = "baz")

sample_list <- list(a = sublist,
                    b = sublist,
                    c = sublist)
```

Here, I would like to create a sublist for the elements in `a` `b` and `c` within each of the aforementioned lists. I.e I would like to nest `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, one list further down, **after I have created the list in the manner above**.

Desired output:

```
sample_list <- list(a = list(a_down = sublist),
                    b = list(b_down = sublist),
                    c = list(c_down = sublist))
```

Comment: Something like `lapply(1:3, function(i) setNames(list(sublist), letters[i]))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `imap`

```
library(purrr)
out2 <- imap(sample_list, ~ set_names(list(.x), paste0(.y, "_down")))
```

or making use of `lst`

```
imap(sample_list, ~ lst(!! paste0(.y, "_down") := .x))
```

-checking with OP's output

```
identical(out, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```